# powerline symbols can not show in my computer

Tags: vim, vim-powerline

It's weird that powerline symbols could not show in my mac(mavericks), but the old powerline symbols could.

I've tried to font-patch a powerline-font and put it into ~/Library/Fonts, which didn't work. (followed the instruction: https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fontpatching.html#usage)

And the old powerline symbols could show only when I put this font(https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles/blob/master/fonts/Inconsolata-dz-Powerline.otf) into ~/Library/Fonts

Comment: screenshot is here: https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/487036/1558269/218f3fc0-4f7a-11e3-9308-26c96cd97aa4.png

Comment: Use powerline's issue tracker. That's what it's made for.

Comment: Do you have `if exists('+guifont') | let &guifont="DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline" | endif` (replace font name with whatever you have installed)?